# Inconsistency with my code, it seems to work on random occasions

Tags: windows, powershell

I have made this code that is meant to download a picture and then set it as a wallpaper. My problem is that sometimes it works a couple of tries in a row and sometimes it doesn't work at all.(I have deleted the picture that is set to be downloaded after every single try.) I would be very happy if someone has the solution to this problem. Anyway,... here is the code:

```sh
Invoke-WebRequest https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp69067421.jpg -o E:\skiniw.jpg

Function Set-WallPaper($Value)
{
    Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -name wallpaper -value $value

    rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
}

Set-WallPaper -value "E:\skiniw.jpg"
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @CherryDT It downloads the picture but it doesnt set it as a wallpaper.

Comment: Possible that the wallpaper isnt fully downloaded before you try to set it. Add error checking and ensure it's fully downloaded and file not "in use" before you set wallpaper.

Comment: @Scepticalist I am new to the whole concept of powershell, so can you give me an example on how to do this so I can implement it into my code?

Comment: Are you sure it downloads? For me, url `https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp69067421.jpg` gives '404 Page not found'

Comment: @Theo I changed the url a little bit for privacy reasons.

Comment: You may want to add a test in a loop after `Invoke-WebRequest` to see if the file has indeed been downloaded and after that [Unblock it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file).

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting for the file to be downloaded and test the file is actually there before setting it as the wallpaper:

```
Start-Job -Name DownloadWallpaper -ScriptBlock { Invoke-WebRequest "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp69067421.jpg" -o "E:\skiniw.jpg" }

Wait-Job -Name DownloadWallpaper

if (Test-Path "E:\skiniw.jpg"){
    Function Set-WallPaper($Value){
        Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -name wallpaper -value $value
        rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
    }
    Set-WallPaper -value "E:\skiniw.jpg"
}
```